# How set a strong cache in webservice

Tags: android, web-services, caching, https

My webservice :

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
        if (params != null) {
            method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
        }
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
```

how set cache for this code ,
Answer the cache without internet

Comment: Not clear what you want. Please elaborate more.

Comment: i want cache all answers

Comment: Ok, you should write some code to do it. Also note that you should be think carefully about rules for your cache entries becoming stale and being removed from the cache at some point or be replaced with newer entries.